# increment list directory number php

Tags: php

this is my first question in this platform, I have the privilege to resolve my coding problems only reading the solutions, but at this time I actually have a single problem with a php code, I don't know how to increment a directory list number, I have already reading a directory folders, I have use "$total++" and declaring before the variable "$total=0" and "$total++" but I let you the code and the screenshots for more information.

**first code and image review.**

```
    <?php
    $directorio = opendir("."); //ruta actual
    while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
    {
        if (is_dir($archivo) && $archivo!="." && $archivo!=".." && $archivo!="css" && $archivo!="js")//verificamos si es o no un directorio y con '&& $archivo!="carpeta" escondemos las carpetas que no deseamos mostrar'
        {
            $folder = $archivo;
            $folder = str_replace("-", " ", $folder);

            $total = count($archivo);
            $total++;

                echo $total;
                echo "<div class='col-md-4 mb-4'>";
                echo "<div class='card text-white bg-dark text-center'>";
                echo "<div class='card-header'>".$folder."</div>";
                echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                echo "<a href='".$archivo."' class='btn btn-success'>Ir al Capitulo ".$total."</a>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
        }

    }
closedir($directorio);
?>
```

[first image don't increment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2ST3.png)

**Second code and image review.**

```
<?php
    $directorio = opendir("."); //ruta actual
    while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
    {

        if (is_dir($archivo) && $archivo!="." && $archivo!=".." && $archivo!="css" && $archivo!="js")//verificamos si es o no un directorio y con '&& $archivo!="carpeta" escondemos las carpetas que no deseamos mostrar'
        {
            $folder = $archivo;
            $folder = str_replace("-", " ", $folder);

            $total++;

                echo $total;
                echo "<div class='col-md-4 mb-4'>";
                echo "<div class='card text-white bg-dark text-center'>";
                echo "<div class='card-header'>".$folder."</div>";
                echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                echo "<a href='".$archivo."' class='btn btn-success'>Ir al Capitulo ".$total."</a>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
        }

    }
closedir($directorio);
?>
```

[second image increment with php error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GalTS.png)

I need a help, I will be vary thankfully.

Comment: Remove $total = count($archivo); line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first block of code, you will need to place `$total = count($archivo);` outside the loop, as it resets it each time; thus not incrementing the value `$total`

And for block two, you need to declare the variable `$total = 0;` outside the loop.

Comment: I tried before place the variable outside the loop but is always tha same issue.

Comment: That's because `$archivo` is declared in the while statement.  You'll have to have that statement somewhere before the `$total` variable is declared.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot.

I declared the variable just before the while statement and is running well. :D